# Datatables AJAX needs alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am currently having a problem with the jQuery Datatables plugin. The browser (IE7) my website is made for is having trouble handing the AJAX request. When I take the alert() out, it doesn't load the Datatables values I get form my PHP (json).

When I leave it in, it gives me the alert, but it also fills the table. Does anyone know a way to check if the ajax request was handled properly, and then proceed to fill the table?

It does work this way in Chrome and FireFox, but for some reason it doesn't in IE.

So: My browser (IE7) doesn't wait for the AJAX call to be handled, when I do not have an alert under the script.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dataTables-example tfoot th.searchable').each( function () {
        var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );
    var data = $.get("/kleurmixer/hmi/view_json2.php?type=2", function(data){
        return data;
    });
    var table = $("#dataTables-example").DataTable(
            {
                "ajax" : {
                    "url" : "/kleurmixer/hmi/view_json2.php?type=2",
                    "dataSrc" : ''
                },
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                    { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 7 ] },
                    { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 8 ] }
                ]
            }
    );
    table.columns().every( function () {
    var that = this;

    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
            that
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        }
    } );
    } );
    $(".dataTables_filter").html("");
    alert();
});
```

Comment: The alert is a blocking mechanism so that might explain why it works though I'm concerned that you're making 2 ajax calls. When I should think that the Datatable could make just the one and use that to populate the table. Perhaps if you showed us the output of `/kleurmixer/hmi/view_json2.php?type=2` - at least truncated...?

Comment: I had to use pastebin because it was quite big: http://pastebin.com/jyMkChF8 ; The output works fine, its something with the request

Comment: Having trouble replicating your code on JSFiddle. But take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/Lap4brgn/7/

Comment: Actually, this might be better: http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/6b50dtdL/ How many columns are you showing etc...?

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/WLoJlxq.png) is what it looks like. I kind of changed your first fiddle to this: http://pastebin.com/NFqRrHXc ; It fills it in properly the first time, but how do I make it refresh now every x seconds, without the page flashing.

Comment: Would the refresh add new rows or refresh all the data in the table?

Comment: Hello @annoyingmouse ; I fixed it in the meantime! I appreciate your help. This is how it ended up: http://pastebin.com/ncUyjnS2